# Meteor - Reloading template section after variable change

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

i want to refresh/reload a part of my template after a variable change so that if the variable is true it shows a content A or else it will show content B. I'm sure this is a quite simple question but i'm having troubles on finding the solution.

Something like this:

```
Template.x.created = function() {
    this.variable = false;
}

Template.x.helpers({
    'getValue': function(){
            return this.variable;
        }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="x"> 
    {{#if getValue}}
     <content A>
    {{else}}
     <content B>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Waiski answer is a good one, but I want to share a simple Template helper I build because a lot of Templates need this:

Using `registerHelper` you can build a global helper like so:

```
Template.registerHelper('get', function (key) {
  let obj = Template.instance()[key]
  return (obj && obj.get) ? obj.get() : obj
})
```

Use it in every template:

```
Template.x.onCreated(function() {
  this.foo = new ReactiveVar(true)
  this.bar = new ReactiveVar('abc')
})
```

Html:

```
{{#let foo=(get 'foo')}}
  {{#if get 'bar'}}
    Bar is true. Foo: {{foo}}
  {{/if}}
{{/let}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a reactive data source to get the template helper to re-run when the variable changes, as a normal variable won't let the helper know when it changes value. The simplest solution is to use [`ReactiveVar`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html):

```js
Template.x.onCreated(function() {
  this.variable = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.x.helpers({
  'getValue': function() {
    // Note that 'this' inside a template helper may not refer to the template instance
    return Template.instance().variable.get();
  }
});
```

If you need to access the value somewhere outside this template, you can use [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) as an alternative reactive data source.